# (IN IOS) Quickblox give bad timestamp error when device's automatically time setting is turn off

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, quickblox

I am using Quickblox sdk ios version.
I am facing a problem while login into Quickblox sdk.

```
 [QBRequest logInWithUserEmail:currentUser.email password:currentUser.password successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {

}errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response)
     {
     }];
```

I got following response :- (If my device's automatically time setting is turn off.)

```
[QBCore] Response error reasons: {
    errors =     {
        base =         (
            "Bad timestamp"
        );
    };
}
2017-02-04 10:26:08.367 MyProeject[9697:143906] [QBAuth] Create Session request error: {"errors":{"base":["Bad timestamp"]}}
```

If my device's automatically time setting is turn on. I am not getting any error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

When SDK creates a session token it passes a 'timestamp' param to server.

It shouldn't be differ from time provided by NTP more than 60 minutes. Otherwise you will be receiving error like that ("Bad timestamp")

API details https://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#Parameters

Comment: How can I fix this in Quickblox's Ios sdk without device's automatically time setting ? Actually my app is live, I can't tell users to set this setting ON.